# Get user_likes and user_posts from Facebook using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, facebook, mongodb, passport.js

I need to develop an App that  get some information by FB (user_posts and  user_likes) I'm trying  implement its using Passport-facebook.
I tried, (just 'likes' to test first)
newUser.facebook.likes = profile.likes[0].value; 
and the error is:
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
'likes' is on my profileFields.
I put my code that is working on [my Github](https://github.com/cmaricy/Vivamente). (whitout likes and posts)
Other information like (id, name, email...) works very well, but I'm not be able to get the data user_likes and user_posts. I would like to enter this data in my MongoDB database.

The method that follow (in Javascript):

```
function getInfo() {        
FB.api('me', {fields :'id,name,posts,likes'}, function(response) {
                var dataStr = "data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(response));
                var dlAnchorElem = document.getElementById('downloadAnchorElem');
                dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("href", dataStr);
                dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("download", "feed.json");
                dlAnchorElem.click();
            });
        };
```

Do what I want, but it writes data (.json) in a file, I want to record in the database and using NodeJS.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of Mongoose and how to define a schema in mongoose.

i suggest that it would be the simplest way for you to do.

you can use json-schema-to-mongoose (see link below for example)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-to-mongoose

and them simply save the document to mongodb.

Comment: Thanks @satishChennupati, I'll folow your tips.